# function always returns true

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that is comparing two arrays. The blacklist array is all lowercase already.

The function always returns true and I don't see why.

```
function flagProfanity(words) {
    var found = false;
    $.each(words, function(key, word){
        if ($.inArray(word.toLowerCase, blacklist) == -1){
            found = true;
        }
    });
    return found;   
}
```

EDIT, these are alerted straight from words, and a censored version of blacklist.

```
k,just,wondering,how,this,mod,thing,works

swear, profanity, bad, word, more, profanity
```

Comment: I assume you want to invoke the `.toLowerCase()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`inArray` returns -1 if the needle is *not* found, so you'll want to set `found` to true if inArray returns a value that's greater than -1.

Also, as Bergi pointed out in the comments you want to call `toLowerCase()`, which is a function, and not `toLowerCase`, which is a property.

```
if ($.inArray(word.toLowerCase(), blacklist) > -1){
  found = true;
}
```

Comment: I changed it and now it doesn't flag anything.

Comment: @jondoe85 can you post some sample data for your words and blacklist?

Comment: Ok, added the examples

Answer (score 1):

That will only return `false` if, and only if, the arrays are **completely** equal. If there is **at least** one element (`word`) that is not in the array, `found` will be set to `true` and that is why it always return `true`.